# Copy sheet name to row with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy the worksheets name into Row 1 of another worksheet of the same file. Here is what I have/need:

- File has different worksheets, but I need only the title from the sheet 3 on
- The worksheet where I want to copy the names is sheet 2
- the names need to be copy on row 1, from cell B1
- I'll run this macro periodically, so I'd need new sheet names to be added every time while keeping there the one already copied.

Can you help me? :)

Comment: Have you tried the cell() function?

Comment: Please, read read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and don't forget to read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) . Also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and ["help center".](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

### List Worksheet Names in a Row

```vb
Sub ListNames()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = wb.Worksheets(2).Range("B1")
    
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 3 To wb.Worksheets.Count
        dCell.Value = wb.Worksheets(n).Name
        Set dCell = dCell.Offset(, 1)
    Next n
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Reading your code and the the OP question again, I understand now what was actually asked for. I think this answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

From what you write it's really hard to tell what you actually need.

The following VBA code writes the name of the 3rd worksheet to the `B1` cell  of sheet 2. If you don't have 3 sheet's nothing happens:

```
Sub WriteTheNameOfWorksheet3IntoWorksheet2CellB1()
   If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count >= 3 Then
      ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Range("B1") = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(3).Name
   End If
End Sub
```